# Databricks zookeeper not starting

Tags: apache-zookeeper, databricks

When Zookeeper is started with the following command, it hangs at the following step and never finishes with the statement 'zookeeper started'

```
INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
```

Since this step is hanging, no further steps would execute in Databricks, as they will show 'Waiting to process'

Steps:

1. Start a Cluster in Databricks
2. Create a notebook (i used both python and scala, got same result below)
3. Install Kafka from here - 
   `%sh wget http://mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache/kafka/2.4.0/kafka_2.12-2.4.0.tgz`
4. `%sh tar -xzf kafka_2.12-2.4.0.tgz`
5. `%sh /databricks/driver/kafka_2.12-2.4.0/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh

   /databricks/driver/kafka_2.12-2.4.0/config/zookeeper.properties`

Do I need to add any library? Could you please point how to get this moving?

Answer (score 0):

Two things.
If you run a `%sh <shell command>` and the command expects some kind of input, then it will definitely 'hang'. You'll have to disconnect and reconnect the notebook from the cluster. Supply the command line arguments to prevent the installation from asking questions (e.g. "Headless" mode)

Secondly, if you want to read from Kafka, you can use Databricks 'Data' button. Go Data -> [Add Data] -> [Other Data Sources] -> [Connector] (select Kafka) to get a notebook generated for you. Fill in the template.
The code generated looks something like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{get_json_object, json_tuple}

var streamingInputDF = 
  spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<server:ip")
    .option("subscribe", "topic1")     
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")  
    .option("minPartitions", "10")  
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "true")
    .load()
```

Databricks comes with the drivers installed. I've used this with good success on AWS MKS on the AWS cloud.